# Fill a data frame that requires the use of preceding rows in different columns in R

Tags: r

I need an efficient way to fill a calculation table that requires the preceding rows in different columns to obtain the current values.

I asked a similar question before but was not clear, so here is a new example code and the way I am currently doing it (slow):

```
df = data.frame(elevation = seq(1,10),
      inflow = c(3,4,6,4,3,5,6,7,8,9),
      outflow = NA,
      storage = NA,
      stat = NA)


for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  
  if (i == 1) {
    
    df$outflow[i] = 0
    df$storage[i] = 0
    df$stat[i] = 0
    
  } else {
    
    df$outflow[i] = df$inflow[i-1]/2 + df$stat[i-1] + df$storage[i-1]
    df$storage[i] = df$inflow[i] - df$outflow[i] + df$stat[i-1]
    df$stat[i] = df$inflow[i-1] + df$stat[i-1] - df$storage[i-1] 
    
  }
  
 
}

df
   elevation inflow outflow storage stat
1          1      3     0.0     0.0  0.0
2          2      4     1.5     2.5  3.0
3          3      6     7.5     1.5  4.5
4          4      4     9.0    -0.5  9.0
5          5      3    10.5     1.5 13.5
6          6      5    16.5     2.0 15.0
7          7      6    19.5     1.5 18.0
8          8      7    22.5     2.5 22.5
9          9      8    28.5     2.0 27.0
10        10      9    33.0     3.0 33.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because each calc relies on the the results of the previous calc, and they may not always align with simple cumulative math (e.g., `cumsum`), we can `Reduce` for the desired results.

```r
# initial conditions
df[1,c("outflow", "storage", "stat")] <- 0
# update each row iteratively
Reduce(function(dat, i) {
  dat$outflow[i] = dat$inflow[i-1]/2 + dat$stat[i-1] + dat$storage[i-1]
  dat$storage[i] = dat$inflow[i] - dat$outflow[i] + dat$stat[i-1]
  dat$stat[i] = dat$inflow[i-1] + dat$stat[i-1] - dat$storage[i-1]
  dat
}, 2:nrow(df), init = df)
#    elevation inflow outflow storage stat
# 1          1      3     0.0     0.0  0.0
# 2          2      4     1.5     2.5  3.0
# 3          3      6     7.5     1.5  4.5
# 4          4      4     9.0    -0.5  9.0
# 5          5      3    10.5     1.5 13.5
# 6          6      5    16.5     2.0 15.0
# 7          7      6    19.5     1.5 18.0
# 8          8      7    22.5     2.5 22.5
# 9          9      8    28.5     2.0 27.0
# 10        10      9    33.0     3.0 33.0
```

The flow of the `Reduce` is to iterate over each of `2:nrow(df)`, and call the function with this number as the second argument (`i`); the first argument of the inner function is the result from the previous call to the function, which on the first call is `init`ialized to `df`. (If we did not provide `init=`, then the two arguments of the inner function would have been the first two values in `2:nrow(df)`, i.e., `2` and `3`, which is not what we need.)

It might be informative (if you want to learn what `Reduce` is doing) to add `accumulate=TRUE` to the call, which shows the value of the data (`dat`) after each call to the inner function:

```r
df[1,c("outflow", "storage", "stat")] <- 0
Reduce(function(dat, i) {
  dat$outflow[i] = dat$inflow[i-1]/2 + dat$stat[i-1] + dat$storage[i-1]
  dat$storage[i] = dat$inflow[i] - dat$outflow[i] + dat$stat[i-1]
  dat$stat[i] = dat$inflow[i-1] + dat$stat[i-1] - dat$storage[i-1]
  dat
}, seq_len(nrow(df))[-1], init = df, accumulate = TRUE)
# [[1]]
#    elevation inflow outflow storage stat
# 1          1      3       0       0    0
# 2          2      4      NA      NA   NA
# 3          3      6      NA      NA   NA
# 4          4      4      NA      NA   NA
# 5          5      3      NA      NA   NA
# 6          6      5      NA      NA   NA
# 7          7      6      NA      NA   NA
# 8          8      7      NA      NA   NA
# 9          9      8      NA      NA   NA
# 10        10      9      NA      NA   NA
# [[2]]
#    elevation inflow outflow storage stat
# 1          1      3     0.0     0.0    0
# 2          2      4     1.5     2.5    3
# 3          3      6      NA      NA   NA
# 4          4      4      NA      NA   NA
# 5          5      3      NA      NA   NA
# 6          6      5      NA      NA   NA
# 7          7      6      NA      NA   NA
# 8          8      7      NA      NA   NA
# 9          9      8      NA      NA   NA
# 10        10      9      NA      NA   NA
# [[3]]
#    elevation inflow outflow storage stat
# 1          1      3     0.0     0.0  0.0
# 2          2      4     1.5     2.5  3.0
# 3          3      6     7.5     1.5  4.5
# 4          4      4      NA      NA   NA
# 5          5      3      NA      NA   NA
# 6          6      5      NA      NA   NA
# 7          7      6      NA      NA   NA
# 8          8      7      NA      NA   NA
# 9          9      8      NA      NA   NA
# 10        10      9      NA      NA   NA
# [[4]]
#    elevation inflow outflow storage stat
# 1          1      3     0.0     0.0  0.0
# 2          2      4     1.5     2.5  3.0
# 3          3      6     7.5     1.5  4.5
# 4          4      4     9.0    -0.5  9.0
# 5          5      3      NA      NA   NA
# 6          6      5      NA      NA   NA
# 7          7      6      NA      NA   NA
# 8          8      7      NA      NA   NA
# 9          9      8      NA      NA   NA
# 10        10      9      NA      NA   NA
# [[5]]
#    elevation inflow outflow storage stat
# 1          1      3     0.0     0.0  0.0
# 2          2      4     1.5     2.5  3.0
# 3          3      6     7.5     1.5  4.5
# 4          4      4     9.0    -0.5  9.0
# 5          5      3    10.5     1.5 13.5
# 6          6      5      NA      NA   NA
# 7          7      6      NA      NA   NA
# 8          8      7      NA      NA   NA
# 9          9      8      NA      NA   NA
# 10        10      9      NA      NA   NA
# [[6]]
#    elevation inflow outflow storage stat
# 1          1      3     0.0     0.0  0.0
# 2          2      4     1.5     2.5  3.0
# 3          3      6     7.5     1.5  4.5
# 4          4      4     9.0    -0.5  9.0
# 5          5      3    10.5     1.5 13.5
# 6          6      5    16.5     2.0 15.0
# 7          7      6      NA      NA   NA
# 8          8      7      NA      NA   NA
# 9          9      8      NA      NA   NA
# 10        10      9      NA      NA   NA
# [[7]]
#    elevation inflow outflow storage stat
# 1          1      3     0.0     0.0  0.0
# 2          2      4     1.5     2.5  3.0
# 3          3      6     7.5     1.5  4.5
# 4          4      4     9.0    -0.5  9.0
# 5          5      3    10.5     1.5 13.5
# 6          6      5    16.5     2.0 15.0
# 7          7      6    19.5     1.5 18.0
# 8          8      7      NA      NA   NA
# 9          9      8      NA      NA   NA
# 10        10      9      NA      NA   NA
# [[8]]
#    elevation inflow outflow storage stat
# 1          1      3     0.0     0.0  0.0
# 2          2      4     1.5     2.5  3.0
# 3          3      6     7.5     1.5  4.5
# 4          4      4     9.0    -0.5  9.0
# 5          5      3    10.5     1.5 13.5
# 6          6      5    16.5     2.0 15.0
# 7          7      6    19.5     1.5 18.0
# 8          8      7    22.5     2.5 22.5
# 9          9      8      NA      NA   NA
# 10        10      9      NA      NA   NA
# [[9]]
#    elevation inflow outflow storage stat
# 1          1      3     0.0     0.0  0.0
# 2          2      4     1.5     2.5  3.0
# 3          3      6     7.5     1.5  4.5
# 4          4      4     9.0    -0.5  9.0
# 5          5      3    10.5     1.5 13.5
# 6          6      5    16.5     2.0 15.0
# 7          7      6    19.5     1.5 18.0
# 8          8      7    22.5     2.5 22.5
# 9          9      8    28.5     2.0 27.0
# 10        10      9      NA      NA   NA
# [[10]]
#    elevation inflow outflow storage stat
# 1          1      3     0.0     0.0  0.0
# 2          2      4     1.5     2.5  3.0
# 3          3      6     7.5     1.5  4.5
# 4          4      4     9.0    -0.5  9.0
# 5          5      3    10.5     1.5 13.5
# 6          6      5    16.5     2.0 15.0
# 7          7      6    19.5     1.5 18.0
# 8          8      7    22.5     2.5 22.5
# 9          9      8    28.5     2.0 27.0
# 10        10      9    33.0     3.0 33.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you think there is a faster way to perform the same operation? What function should I search for?

Comment: When you have bespoke calculations that rely on multiple columns' previous and current row values, there is (imo) no way to make it any faster. If you truly need to speed it up, I suggest `Rcpp` or `cpp11` for C++ speed improvements: much faster but requires an extra compilation step plus expanding your brain out of R (though I don't think _these_ calculations would be too difficult for you to implement). If you want to go that route and you aren't comfortable with C++, I strongly urge using somebody else's already-working C++ code as a template so you don't make newbie mistakes.

Comment: What do you think about ```c#```?

Comment: No strong opinion, though I've not seen easy ways to link C# apps into an R app. That's not saying I know there a problems, it might be just as easy once the `.so`/`.dll` object is created, but I've not seen it. Over to you: find something that you can write/maintain and can easily integrate into an R workflow.